# When setrepeatcount is not 0, my animation does not show

Tags: ios, objective-c

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjjPkmcwdQc

Hello.

I'm following the above tutorial exactly. However, when i change the number of setrepeatcount to not be 0, the animation does not appear. It is just blank. Can anyone tell me why this is? This works, even if I have the values at 5000. I don't think the animation is playing too fast, since, when it is 0, each frame appears in a reasonable about of time (.5s).

here is an example of the code in the viewcontroller file. IT is the onl

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AnimPanel.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Anim1.png"],
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Anim2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Anim3.png"],nil];

    AnimPanel.animationDuration = 2.5;
   // [AnimPanel setAnimationRepeatCount:5000];
        [AnimPanel startAnimating];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setAnimationRepeatCount has nothing to do with faster or slower animation, this will only repeat your animation to count number of times.
If you set repeat count as 1 in below code snippet you will not able to see any animation, however you will see when you set any value > 1.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    AnimPanel.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Anim1.png"],
          [UIImage imageNamed:@"Anim2.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"Anim3.png"],nil];

    AnimPanel.animationDuration = 2.5;
   // [AnimPanel setAnimationRepeatCount:5000];
    [AnimPanel startAnimating];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Reason:- why it is not shown for count 1 is view did load called before view is shown to you, so if you want to have animation just one time, you can move this animation code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` method, then you will be able to see the animation even if repeatCount is 1.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   // write your code here.
 }
```

Comment: Ok but the issue I'm having is that, even if the count number is high, it does not show. Furthermore, why does an infinite count show?

Comment: It seems if you call startAnimating in viewDidLoad, the animation won't start there. Animation will not be active in a controller which has not been not displayed yet.
You need to call the startAnimating in viewDidAppear instead. there must be some time post which your animation start showing, that depend of the time once view is completely loaded.

Comment: Here is the thing. If I use the example from this link, it works perfectly. And in this case the animation is loaded from viewdidload.

EDIT: Here is the link in question. 

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/

Comment: there is difference in what is present on tutorial, [super viewDidLoad]; line of code is called in the last so all the view loaded activities are move for later. Have you tried what i suggested>

Comment: I don't see a function for viewdid appear. Where is it called.

Comment: check updated answer, it is also a view controller life cycle method.

Comment: In the link posted, the code is still called from ViewDidload.

Comment: @ElliottMiller then follow above code, which i have edited in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: IT WORKS WOW

Can I commend you?

Comment: Not clear what you say in earlier comment? If your issue is solved, you can accept the answer and close the question.